# Does upvoting during Review Audits upvote for real?

Tags: support, review-audits

I just did a review audit, and I thought the answer was a good answer. I hit the 'No Action Needed' button (and passed!), but I am wondering: If I hit the Upvote button, would the question/answer actually get the vote? If not, what is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: I think the review would actually be deleted the time you are reviewing it.

Comment: @user689 OP apparently refers "known good" kind audit (as only these pass at _'No Action Needed'_) - these are supposed to be real, available posts

Comment: And what would happen if you were presented with a post that you've already upvoted!? (Or is the audit system smart enough not to present you such a post?)